# Setting minimum and maximum value using regex

Tags: regex, wpf

I want a textbox to have a value between 0 and 24. However the below pattern does not seem to be working.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^([0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])$");
```

Comment: A regex is the wrong tool for this job. If you're in WPF you can use the [Range] attribute as a validator.

Comment: The pattern itself seems to work. https://regex101.com/r/G2u8Yq/1 Perhaps [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734511/how-can-i-set-regular-expression-on-textbox) can be helpful.

Comment: Making the Range attribute play nicely with WPF [requires a bit more work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939996/having-range-attribute-and-one-extra-number/29940586#comment48001779_29939996). And note that [the documentation for RangeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute?view=netframework-4.8) demonstrates its use with fields, but in WPF you must use a property for Bindings to work.

Comment: What are you actually doing with that regex? Please provide [a minimal working example](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/MVCE) of your validation scheme, XAML and C#, for one property using that regex, and explain exactly what is "not working".

Comment: Can't you just cast it to an `int` or `double` or whatever you need and then check if it's between 0 and 24? Feels like that would make your intentions way clearer

Comment: Yup. Exactly what I did later @IDarkCoder

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what WPF is, but this expression might likely validate 0-24:

```
^[0-9]$|^[1][0-9]$|^[2][0-4]$
```

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/UIHLCU/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.